# Как прочитать неопределенное количество строк с клавиатуры?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо ввести с клавиатуры определенной число строк, содержащих float числа. В первой строке вводится число - количество строк, в каждой последующей строке вводится два float числа.
Мой вариант для 3 строк выглядит так:

```
N = int(input())
a1 = list(map(float, input().split()))
a2 = list(map(float, input().split()))
a3 = list(map(float, input().split()))
b1 = a1[0], a2[0], a3[0]
b2 = a1[1], a2[1], a3[1]
```

Но что делать если количество строк заранее не известно и может быть 5, 6 и т.д.
Подскажите как будет выглядеть код, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте цикл, и сохраняйте данный в список списков:

```
n = int(input())

b = []
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(float, input().split()))
    b.append(a)

print(b)
```